# The argument type 'RxList<Streams>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<Streams>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using streambuilder to fetch data but I keep getting its err

**The argument type 'RxList' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream?'**

**Here is my StreamBuilder**

```
                   StreamBuilder<Streams>(
                    stream: _streamsController.streamList,
                    builder: (
                      BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<Streams> snapshot,
                    ) {
                      if (ConnectionState.waiting == snapshot.connectionState) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: ProjectColors.primary,
                          ),
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: _streamsController.streamList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: width * 0.02),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () => Get.to(
                                  () => DetailsScreen(
                                    stream:
                                        _streamsController.streamList[index],
                                  ),
                                  arguments: [
                                    _streamByBooks.books[index].title,
                                    _streamsController
                                        .streamList[index].description,
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      _streamByBooks.books
                                          .map((e) => e.image)
                                          .toList()[index],
                                      height: height * 0.25,
                                      width: width * 0.3,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: height * 0.007),
                                    Text(
                                      _streamsController.streamList
                                          .map((element) => element.stream)
                                          .toList()[index]
                                          .toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: ProjectColors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
                      }
                    },
                  )
```

**Here is my Stream Controller class**

```
class StreamsController extends GetxController {
  RxList<Streams> streamList = <Streams>[].obs;

  void getStreams() async {
    List<Streams> streamVariable = await RetrieveStreams.fetchStreams();
    streamList.value = streamVariable;
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    getStreams();
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

**The Stream is a model class and here is that class**

```
List<Streams> streamsListFromJson(String str) =>
    (json.decode(str) as List<dynamic>)
        .map((s) => Streams.fromJson(s))
        .toList();

String streamsListToJson(List<Streams> data) =>
    json.encode(data.map((s) => s.toJson()).toList());

class Streams {
  Streams({
    required this.title,
    required this.stream,
    
  });

  String title;
  String stream;
 

  factory Streams.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Streams(
        title: json["title"],
        stream: json["stream"],
        
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title,
        "stream": stream,
        
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your stream is

```
 stream: _streamsController.streamList,
```

and your streamList datatype is

```
RxList<Streams>
```

and StreamBuldir received type of

```
<Streams>
```

so its not match

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

try this

```
class StreamsController extends GetxController {
RxList<Streams> _streamList =[].obs;
 get streamList async*{
 yield _streamList.value;
//it will return List<Streams> as a stream}

 

 void getStreams() async {
  List<Streams> streamVariable = await RetrieveStreams.fetchStreams();
  streamList.value = streamVariable;
}

 @override
 void onInit() {
   getStreams();
   super.onInit();
 }
}
```

try this Example to know more about stream:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  getRandomValues().listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}

Stream<String> getRandomValues() async* {
  var random = Random(2);
 while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield "1st: ${random.nextDouble()}";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. After implementing your suggestion, this is the error I am getting now. _TypeError (type 'RxList<Streams>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<Streams>?') and debugger is point at the value of the stream (that is                     stream: _streamsController.streamList,
) on the StreamBuilder function

Comment: it is because we return a list of objects as a stream

Comment: try this 
stream: _streamsController.streamList[0],

Comment: this was the response RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Comment: getStreams() async*{
  List<Streams> streamVariable = await RetrieveStreams.fetchStreams();
  streamList.value = streamVariable;
yield _streamList.value;
}

/////////////
stream:getStreams(),

Comment: your error happens because  your list is still empty

Comment: Okay. then I will check on that